# Calling SignalR group from controller in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

So first off the problem referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239040/how-to-validate-azure-ad-b2c-token-from-query-string-in-asp-net-core) question is what I was initially having. Not being able to tie Azure Active Directory B2C's JWT token into SignalR; or not understanding how to anyway.

Since no one has really given a solution to the above problem, specifically in .NET Core that I can find online, I resorted to the following...

```
[Route("api/NotificationsChannel")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConnectToNotificationsChannel(string connectionId)
{
    string userId = await userService.GetUserIdAsync();
    try
    {
        await _hubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, userId);
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, "Connected to Notifications");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Could not connect to group");
    }
}
```

With the above, from my client I pass the `connectionId` to create a group associated with the `UserId` collected from `HttpContextAccessor` aka the JWT authorized by Azure Active Directory.

Then whenever I need to fire a notification off to the logged in user, it's simple and has so far worked fine for me. See the below for how I'm going about this...

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/GiftLists/")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateList(GiftListDto glist)
{
    ...

    var userId = await userService.GetUserIdAsync();

    ...
    await _hubContext.Clients.Group(userId).SendAsync("Notification", NotificationConstants.ListCreatedNotifTitle);
    ...
}
```

Now the problem I'm having is when I want to communicate to another user; for context, a contact of this user instance. They too, if online, should be connected to a group referenced by their userId. So in essence I should be able to connect to that group and send them messages. In this case, I want to notify them when the current user has shared a list with them.

I've tried this...

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/ShareGiftList")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShareGiftList(GListShareDTO listShare)
{
    ...

    // Below is where I believe I would need to connect the current user
    // to the contact's group to send messages to them, but how
    // do I get the connectionId without having to pass it in from my client?

    //await _hubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(_hubContext., list.Contact.UserId);
    await _hubContext.Clients.Group(list.Contact.UserId).SendAsync("Notification", NotificationConstants.ListShareSuccessNotifTitle);

}
```

Again by searching the internet or another stackoverflow Q/A I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908620/how-to-obtain-connection-id-of-signalr-client-on-the-server-side).

This is great and seems like it would solve my problem, except I can't access my user's name or anything to do with him, since I couldn't get Authorization to work.

So, can anyone point me in the right direction? The only work-around I can think of is attaching the connectionId to every api request I make from my client. Or invoking a function before making my api call which sets the current user's name.